# Code review and testing in the process

Tags: testing, development-process, code-reviews, jira

I am thinking about the software development process of my team, more specifically, I am thinking about tests and  code review into our development process.
I came to the conclusion that, in order to validate a development task, the development done has to be tested by one tester, and the code has to be reviewed, either by me or by another developer.

I don't see any difference between reviewing the code first or testing it first, if any validation fails, the task has to be modified, and therefore re-tested, and re-reviewed. That's why I would like that once a task has been finished by a developer, it can be assigned to both a tester and a reviewer, and everyone can do their part of the validation when they have time.

However, in our tool (Jira), we can only have one status (like IN TEST) for a task and one assignee (the tester), but we cannot have two status IN TEST & PENDING REVIEW with one assignee for each. Therefore, here are my two questions :

- Is there any drawback to assigning two different person at the same time to validate the same task? It looks strange to me that Jira doesn't allow this to be done if it is a good practice.
- If you consider it as a valid process, how can I implement it into Jira in a simple way?

Answer (score 1):

There is one drawback:

- Assigning both tasks in parallel (to two different people) may result in wasted effort, if both end up working in parallel (and reject the change).

Consider (measure) how much the two kinds of tasks cost, and how likely they are to result in further changes before acceptance.  With those numbers available, you can estimate if it clearly makes sense to schedule one of the two tasks first, and the other one only if the first is passed.

Comment: I'm not sure this would result in wasted effort, since QA would say it doesn't work in case A with parameters aa while Code review would say : this function B could be refactored in such way in order to improve lisibility/modularity. Fixing case A may lead to a refactoring of B, but I think it's unlikely.
Good point for measuring though!